# Dialog saving every file, not selected file from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the below properties to bind to a listbox. The listbox displays files and can execute the Save method to open a SaveDialogBox.

The problem I am having is the dialog comes up for every file in the collection not the selecteditem file I click on from the listbox.  Below is the code, am I missing something?

```
public ObservableCollection<Files> FilesProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return mFilesProperty;
            }
        }



public Files FilesSelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return mFilesSelectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            mFilesSelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FilesSelectedItem");
        }
    }
```

This is the method that executes the save.

```
private void Save(object parameter)
        {

            SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            {
                dlg.AddExtension = true;
                dlg.DefaultExt = "xlsx";
                dlg.Filter = "New Excel(*.xlsx)|*.*";
                foreach (var files in FilesProperty)
                {
                    if (dlg.ShowDialog() ?? false)
                    {

                        File.WriteAllBytes(dlg.FileName, files.Data);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the base code for the listbox there is more code for the xaml, but it is too long.

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2"
             ItemsSource="{Binding FilesProperty}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding FilesSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
             BorderThickness="1"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going to save selected item?

So you shold save data stored in `FilesSelectedItem` propetry. Also, you should check if it is not null.

Your mistake was the following: you tryed to iterate through the `FilesProperty` collection.

```
   private void Save(object parameter)
    {
        SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        {
            dlg.AddExtension = true;
            dlg.DefaultExt = "xlsx";
            dlg.Filter = "New Excel(*.xlsx)|*.*";
            var file = FilesSelectedItem;

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() ?? false)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(dlg.FileName, file);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I am going to save the selected item.